# Nested loop to find most recent comment

Tags: r

I have a table that includes 18 variables containing comments (updates) on items of workflow in a business. Those variables are named *comment_0* to *comment_17*.

Each time a new comments is added it is inserted into the highest blank space for each respective row (i.e. if there had been 2 previous comments then the next comment is added under the *comment_2* column).

I need to create a new column which copies the latest comment for each respective row. The content of this column has been mocked up in the data below under '*new_column*'.

**Data:**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "comment_0   comment_1   comment_2   comment_3   comment_4   comment_5   new_column
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
           text0   text1   text2   text3   text4   text5   text5
           NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
           text0   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  text0
           NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
           NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
           text0   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  text0
           text0   text1   text2   NA  NA  NA  text2
           text0   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  text0
           text0   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  text0", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the dataframe, then get the first non-NA value using *dplyr::coalesce*:

```
library(dplyr)

coalesce(!!!df1[, 6:1])
# [1] NA      "text5" NA      "text0" NA      NA      "text0" "text2" "text0" "text0"

# test
identical(df1$new_column, coalesce(!!!df1[, 6:1]))
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use loops, we can use `max.col` with `ties.method = "last"` to get the index of column for last non-NA entry in every row, use `cbind` to create row-col pair and then subset the dataframe.

```
df$new_column <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(!is.na(df), ties.method = "last"))]

df
#   comment_0 comment_1 comment_2 comment_3 comment_4 comment_5 new_column
#1       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>       <NA>
#2      text0     text1     text2     text3     text4     text5      text5
#3       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>       <NA>
#4      text0      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      text0
#5       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>       <NA>
#6       <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>       <NA>
#7      text0      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      text0
#8      text0     text1     text2      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      text2
#9      text0      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      text0
#10     text0      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>      text0
```

---

We can also use `apply` (not recommended when you can `max.col`) row-wise (with `MARGIN = 1`) and get the last non-NA value in every row.

```
df$new_column <- apply(df, 1, function(x)  x[which.max(cumsum(!is.na(x)))])
```